# I am unable to understand my confusion matrix which I got after removing OHE using argmax()

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am unable to interpret my confusion matrix. I was getting below value error.

**ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported**

After reading number of posts, I realised that issue might have been due to **OHE(one hot encoding)** in predictions. So to resolve it, I used argmax() as suggested in various posts. Below is my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(Y.shape)
print(predictions.shape)
print(Y)
print(predictions)
# print(confusion_matrix(Y, predictions))
print(confusion_matrix(Y.argmax(axis = 1), predictions.argmax(axis = 1)))

(1, 200)
(1, 200)
[[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]]
[[1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]]
[[1]]
```

As can be seen in the output, I am getting `[[1]]` as confusion matrix. I don't know how to interpret it. I was expecting a 2x2 confusion matrix and then I would have gone on to calculate Precision, Recall, F1 Score etc. to know the performance of my model. Please suggest what is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem IIUC is in the input array's shapes. You need to flatten them first. Here's an example reproducing your case:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

Y = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(1,10))
pred = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(1,10))
```

Since both arrays are 2D as in your example, `confusion_matrix` interprets that you have multilabel outputs, which it does not support:

```
confusion_matrix(Y, pred)
ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported
```

You need to flatten both arrays:

```
confusion_matrix(Y.ravel(), pred.ravel())
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct given the other information. Since Y'shape is  (1,200), that suggests that you have 1 sample which has 200 classes. When you do argmax() on that, you will get an output of size (1,1). A confusion matrix is of size (n_classes, n_classes). Since you only have one sample, the confusion matrix will be of size (1,1).

To solve the problem, either you need to pass more than one sample or ensure that argmax is doing what is intended (i.e. are you sure the output is OHE)? If your output is not OHE, then you simply need to reshape the predictions before getting the confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

Y = np.squeeze(Y) #should result in shape (200,)
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions) #should result in shape (200,)

cf = confusion_matrix(Y, predictions) #should result in shape (2, 2) if 2 classes
```

Comment: My problem has two classes i.e. 0,1. So Y will have only one label for each sample(either 0 or 1). Same for predictions. Hence, I believe shapes would be same in classification problem. Given the error "ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported", I concluded that it may be OHE problem.

Comment: Got it. So it seems like your prediction array is not actually one-hot encoded -- 0 and 1 are the classes itself. Try np.squeeze() before getting the confusion matrix.

Comment: Yes, I considered that possibility and tried that. It gives "AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1" error in that case.

Comment: It should be squeezing on axis=0. Try `np.squeeze(Y, axis=0)`.

Comment: I tried. It gives "TypeError: Singleton array 0 cannot be considered a valid collection."

Comment: Is this error on `np.squeeze(Y)` line? Another way to ensure is to manually reshape it: `Y = Y.reshape(Y.shape[1],)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220877/discussion-between-akanksha-atrey-and-deepak-dhiman).